# How to create a TX on the front end (Wallet Adapter) and confirm it on the back end!

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, confirmtransaction

Our web app charges users X amount of SPL token.  Users sign through their connected wallet.  After the tx charges them, a request is sent to the back end where our server changes some metadata on their nft.

Goal: I would like to confirm that the tx executed correctly on the server.  The reason is to prevent users from sending bogus requests to our backend and bypassing the front end SPL token tx.

Problem:  The following code does not work.  It never finds the tx.  Oh, I also don't know what maxSupportedTransactionVersion should be set to lol

```
const tx = await connection.getTransaction(txSig, {
       maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 100000000000000,
     });

     if (!tx) {
       throw new TRPCError({
         code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
         message: "Invalid TX",
         // optional: pass the original error to retain stack trace
       });
     }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Follow Up**
It was suggested that we use `connection.confirmTransaction()`.  The code above was failing because `getTransaction` defaults to only giving you transactions at finalized `commitment` (eg. they have achieved the maximum number of confirmations).

Not sure how to use `connection.confirmTransaction()` on our server.  There is no parameter to specify the tx we are confirming!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the method signature for [`confirmTransaction()`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#confirmTransaction):

```
export type BlockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight = Readonly<{
  blockhash: Blockhash;
  lastValidBlockHeight: number;
}>;

export type BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
  signature: TransactionSignature;
} & BlockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight;

confirmTransaction(
  strategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy,
  commitment?: Commitment,
): Promise<RpcResponseAndContext<SignatureResult>>;
```

So, essentially, your call will look like this:

```
try {
  await connection.confirmTransaction({
    signature: txSig,
    blockhash: '...', // The latest blockhash that you used to submit it.
    lastValidBlockHeight: ..., // The block height after which that hash is no longer valid
  });
} catch (e) {
  // The transaction failed to confirm
}
```

You obtained `blockhash` and `lastValidBlockHeight` when you called `connection.getLatestBlockhash()` to construct the transaction in the first place.

Comment: How do you ensure that txSig is of type BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy?

Comment: `BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy` is actually an _object_ that _contains_ a `signature` property that must be of type `TransactionSignature`. The `TransactionSignature` is basically an alias for `string`. Taken all together, the `BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy` is an object with three properties in it: `signature`, `blockhash`, and `lastValidBlockHeight`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, I just tried creating an object of {signature, blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight} and it no longer directs me to the deprecated function. Ty:)